# Installing package in SDK 29+ - Using PackageInstaller/PackageManager

Tags: android, packageinstaller

Summary: How do I use PackageInstaller to install a package that has been downloaded to an android tablet SDK 29+?

I am attempting to download and install a package via my android app after updating the targetSDK to 29. Everything worked with the target being <23 using `Uri.fromFile` and `startActivity`.  See my code below for an example.

```
        if(result) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        String filePath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + DOWNLOAD_DIR + updateContext.getFilename();
        if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 29) {
            Ln.i("Inside < 29");
            File file = new File(filePath);
            Ln.i(filePath);
            Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file); //For < SDK 24
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
                uri = FileProvider.getUriForFile(
                        context, context.getApplicationContext()
                                .getPackageName() + ".provider", file);
            }
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
            if(updateContext != UpdateContext.SELF) {
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            }
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
            context.startActivity(intent);
        } else {
            Ln.i("Ran 29+ install");
            InstallPackageAndroidQAndAbove(context, filePath, intent);
        }
    }
```

```
    static void InstallPackageAndroidQAndAbove(Context context, String filePath, Intent intent) {
        int sessionId = 0;
        PackageInstaller.Session session = null;
        PackageInstaller packageInstaller = context.getPackageManager().getPackageInstaller();
        PackageInstaller.SessionParams sessionParams = new PackageInstaller.SessionParams(PackageInstaller.SessionParams.MODE_FULL_INSTALL);
        sessionParams.setAppPackageName(context.getApplicationContext().getPackageName());

        try {
            sessionId = packageInstaller.createSession(sessionParams);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Ln.e("Could not create session");
        }

        try {
            session = packageInstaller.openSession(sessionId);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            Ln.e("Could not open session");
        }

        intent.setAction("ACTION_INSTALL_COMPLETE");

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
                context,
                sessionId,
                intent,
                0);

        IntentSender statusReceiver = pendingIntent.getIntentSender();

        session.commit(statusReceiver);
    }
```

When running on a tablet with Android 29+, the file downloads in the correct location.  The install window opens for a split second and then closes automatically. No warnings in console, just a silent defeat.

I imagine it's some issue with my understanding of how PackageInstaller works.  It's also possible the issue lies with the FileProvider call `FileProvider.getUriForFile` in the first method.